# GEP segmentation fault LLVM C++ API

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am sure that this is really simple but, I have been trying to figure it out for more than an hour and I cannot figure it out.

The following code gives me a segmentation fault:

```
Value *newArray = mBuilder.CreateGEP(alloca, value); // alloca is a `StructType`
```

but this does not

```
Value *newArray = mBuilder.CreateGEP(alloca, ConstantInt::get(mContext, APInt(32, 0)));
```

#### Value of `value`

```
%bar1 = load double, double* %bar
%3 = fptoui double %bar1 to i32
```

#### Debugging

When I debug it using lldb I get:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00000001000b9e6e a.out`llvm::PointerType::get(llvm::Type*, unsigned int) + 20
a.out`llvm::PointerType::get:
->  0x1000b9e6e <+20>: movq   (%rdi), %rax
```

#### Question

Why am I getting a segmentation fault and how do I fix it?

#### How to reproduce the problem?

The following code reproduces the problem:

```
#include <vector>

#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Value.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/APFloat.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/APInt.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"

using namespace llvm;

static LLVMContext mContext;
static IRBuilder<> mBuilder(mContext);
static std::unique_ptr<Module> mModule = make_unique<Module>("example", mContext);
static Module *M = mModule.get();

static Type *dType = Type::getDoubleTy(mContext);
static Type *i32 = IntegerType::get(mContext, 32);

// helper functions
static AllocaInst *entryCreateBlockAllocaType(Function *func, std::string name, Type* type) {
  IRBuilder<> tmpBuilder(&func->getEntryBlock(), func->getEntryBlock().begin());
  return tmpBuilder.CreateAlloca(type, nullptr, name);
}

static ArrayRef<Value *> PrefixZero (Value *index) {
  std::vector<Value *> out;
  out.push_back(ConstantInt::get(mContext, APInt(32, 0)));
  out.push_back(index);
  return ArrayRef<Value *>(out);
}

static AllocaInst *createVariable () {
  auto *func = mBuilder.GetInsertBlock()->getParent();
  auto *initValue = ConstantInt::get(mContext, APInt(32, 0));

  auto *alloca = entryCreateBlockAllocaType(func, "var", initValue->getType());
  mBuilder.CreateStore(initValue, alloca);
  return alloca; 
}

static std::vector<Type *> elementTypes (3, dType);
static AllocaInst *createStruct () {
  auto *func = mBuilder.GetInsertBlock()->getParent();

  auto *mStructType = StructType::get(mContext, elementTypes);
  return entryCreateBlockAllocaType(func, "str", mStructType);
}

int main () {
  // create a main function
  auto *FT = FunctionType::get(i32, std::vector<Type *>(), false);
  auto *f = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", M);

  // set insert point for out below code
  auto *bb = BasicBlock::Create(mContext, "entry", f);
  mBuilder.SetInsertPoint(bb);

  // Create a variable
  auto *variable = createVariable();
  // create a struct
  auto *mStruct = createStruct();

  // Create a GEP with the loaded index
  auto *loadedVar = mBuilder.CreateLoad(variable, "loaded_index");

  // This is where the problem is.
  // If `PrefixZero` is changed to `ConstantInt::get(mContext, APInt(32, 0))` this works
  auto *elementPtr = mBuilder.CreateGEP(mStruct, PrefixZero(loadedVar)); 

  mBuilder.CreateRet(ConstantInt::get(mContext, APInt(32, 0))); 
  f->print(errs()); // print out the function

  return 1;
}
```

[The code can also be checked out here.](https://github.com/pudility/GEP_Segmentation_fault)

Comment: Is `alloca` a struct or a pointer to a struct? GEP always takes a pointer. If you haven't already, try building LLVM with assertions enabled. Hopefully this will give you an assertion error with a proper error message rather than a segmentation fault. If that doesn't help, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I or someone else can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks. It is a pointer to a struct type (`Builder.CreateAlloca`). I will try building llvm with assertions enabled and update my question accordingly.

Comment: @sepp2k I built llvm with `-LLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON` but nothing changed (AFAIK). I have updated the question with a link to a repository that I made which shows how to reproduce the problem. https://github.com/pudility/GEP_Segmentation_fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. ```
   static ArrayRef<Value *> PrefixZero (Value *index) {
     std::vector<Value *> out;
     out.push_back(ConstantInt::get(mContext, APInt(32, 0)));
     out.push_back(index);
     return ArrayRef<Value *>(out);
   }
   ```

   From the [documentation of `ArrayRef`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html#details):

   > This class does not own the underlying data, it is expected to be used in situations where the data resides in some other buffer, whose lifetime extends past that of the ArrayRef.

   In other words returning an `ArrayRef` to a local variable is illegal in the same way that returning a pointer to a local variable would be. Internally the `ArrayRef` just stores `out`'s `data` pointer and as soon as `out` goes out of scope (i.e. at the end of `PrefixZero`), the `data` is freed and the `ArrayRef` now contains a pointer to freed memory.
2. When using `getelementptr` on a struct, the index that represent the member access (i.e. the second index in your case) must be a constant. If you think about it, it would be impossible to typecheck the instruction otherwise (keeping in mind that usually the members of a struct don't all have the same type). Plus calculating the pointer offset for a given non-constant index would basically have to generate an entire lookup table and it would be counter-intuitive for a pointer-arithmetic instruction to generate that much code. You can think of GEP on a struct as equivalent to `the_struct.member_name` in C and you can't replace `member_name` with a variable there either.

Note that, if assertions are enabled in your build of LLVM, the second issue should cause an assertion failure "Invalid GetElementPtrInst indices for type!", which, while not quite telling you everything you need to know (like in what way the indices are invalid), does point you in the right direction a lot more than just "segmentation fault" would. So if you didn't get that message, make sure you have assertions enabled, so you can benefit from the assertion messages the next time you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. Only thing is that its kind of weird how it works with ArrayTypes, just not StructTypes. How would you suggest I get an element at an index of a variable? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @pudility If I change `createStruct` to return an array instead, I still get a segfault, so I don't think "it works with ArrayTypes, just not StructTypes" is completely true (though compiler versions and optimization settings can affect this as well). That said, accessing freed memory is UB, so any changes you make to the code can cause it to appear to work without actually fixing the problem. You can use `valgrind` or sanitizers to find memory problems even in programs that appear to work. But it appears that this isn't the only problem in your code. I'll take a closer look later.

Comment: @pudility The second problem is that structs can only be indexed with constant indices, not variables.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks for the help. One more question but, I don't think its worth opening another issue for. Do you know why I cannot cast the index (`%3 = fptoui double %bar1 to i32`) to a constant int (`dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(index)`)?

Comment: @pudility Because it's not a `ConstantInt`, it's an `FPToUIInst`. If something is the result of some instruction and not an integer literal, then it's not an instance of `ConstantInt` and can't be cast as such. Can you explain what you're trying to do? Why do you have an index of a struct member that starts out as a double? What does the corresponding code in your source language look like? If your language allows dynamic access of member variables in structs (though I'd expect that to work with strings, not doubles), you'll need a more complicated representation in LLVM.

Comment: Thanks that explains it. I am using doubles so that I can just have one type of number in the toy language I am making (for now). Here is a link to the code if you want to look at it https://github.com/pudility/superFlow/blob/master/ast/ast.cpp#L116-L119 thanks again for the help!

Comment: @pudility What I'm asking is why there are numbers involved at all on the frontend side. Usually a struct access in the surface language would look something like `my_struct.x`, then you'd look up "x" in a table of members for the given struct type, find out its index is, say, 1 (which you can store as an actual integer regardless of which types of numbers your language supports because we're not talking about code in your language at that point) and then generate a GEP with indices 0,1.

Comment: I am not sure I follow completely. If for example someone has a double called `i` (in my toy language) I want to be able to do `somestruct[i]` I then convert `i` to an int and use GEP to get the element. My code works fine with this instead `somestruct[1]`. It is just with the variable where I run into problems. The other weird thing is the code I liked to above is very similar (Arrays instead of Structs) but, both literal numbers and variables work with that. Sorry for such a long comment and thanks again for the help.

Comment: Actually I think I get what you are saying and I think I am doing most of that. The only issue is that I am storing the index as an `llvm::Value` because I am not sure if it might also be used for other things.

Comment: @pudility I think your language's idea of what a struct is differs widely from other languages and from LLVM. In C++, for example, you'd define a struct like this: `struct Point { double x; double y; }` and then you could use it like `Point p; p.x = ...; p.y = ...;`. This does not involve square brackets or numbers - those would be for arrays.

Comment: I agree - it is a little weird. I am having a bit of a hard time figuring out how to implement arrays. I actually asked a question about this (link below if you are interested) and I was recommended to use some sort of object. I originally used arrays but that proved to have several problems (I won't go over those here because its all in the question). Anyway that clears up what you were saying about a table - thanks! Also I really appreciate you taking the time to explain all this to me :) Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842415/how-to-implement-arrays-llvm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173301/discussion-between-sepp2k-and-pudility).

Comment: Okay, see you in the chat.